# SetTheme to an activity with PreferencesDataStore

Tags: android, android-theme, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-datastore

I have switched my app from using `SharedPreferences` to `PreferencesDataStore`. I have also implemented a dark mode and several themes inside my app. For theming, I basically rely in each activity on this code:

```
    val themePreferences = getSharedPreferences("THEME_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val settingsPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE)
    darkMode = settingsPreferences.getBoolean("darkMode", false)

    setTheme(when (darkMode) {
        true -> themePreferences.getInt("themeDark", R.style.AppThemeDark)
        false -> themePreferences.getInt("themeLight", R.style.AppThemeLight)
    })
```

The selected theme gets stored as an Integer, each once for the light mode as well as the dark mode. Now, I also want to adopt this section of my code. I get my darkMode boolean from my dataStore repository like this:

```
viewModel.storedDarkMode.observe(this) { darkMode = it }
```

If I work inside the observe(this) { ... } of the LiveData object it won't work.

Now, how can I change my code snippet shown above to `PreferencesDataStore`? Or is it actually better e.g. to make a separate class in order to observe the values from there? If yes, how could something like that look like? Or do you know some good example code following Android Architecture including custom themes with a dark mode where I can look at?

I am still learning a lot, any help for better understanding this is much appreciated!

Best regards, Markus

**Edit**:

```
runBlocking {
        val darkMode = viewModel.darkModeFlow.first()
        setTheme(when (darkMode) {
            true -> viewModel.themeDarkFlow.first()
            false -> viewModel.themeLightFlow.first()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is best practice or not, but I use `runBlocking` to get theme data from `dataStore`. It is always recommended that, we should never use `runBlocking` in our production code.

```
val preferences = runBlocking {
    mainActivityViewModel.preferencesFlow.first()
}
setAppTheme(preferences.currentTheme)
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

In `setAppTheme` method

```
private fun setAppTheme(theme: Boolean) {
        mainActivityViewModel.darkMode = theme
        //set your theme here
    }
```

Now observe `preferencesFlow` for any change in theme value, and if the theme is changed then `recreate()`

```
mainActivityViewModel.preferencesLiveData.observe(this) {
        if (it.currentTheme != mainActivityViewModel.selectedTheme) {
            recreate()
        }
    }
```

As we can't load our UI, without getting the theme. It seemed right to use `runBlocking`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since runBlocking then freezes the UI thread, have you got any ANR's with this approach?

Comment: Not even a single one.

Comment: Hoenstly, I don't really like the usage of runBlocking, but it works fine. Do you see any problems with the code that I have edited below my question?

Comment: Edit: One more thing, this solution doen't work for me until when the Flow value itself changes. What I would need to do is to recreate also the ViewModel itself, but thats not possible what if have seen so far. What's curious to me at the moment is, that when I recreate my Activity, sometimes the Flow adopts to changes, but often not. While when I relaunch it completely, it works as intended.

Comment: You should take your `setTheme` method call out of the `runBlocking`, Why are you using two different `flows` for storing the same value and for storing the current theme, you shouldn't need to have a `flow`, you should use a normal `boolean` variable. You've to observe `liveData` of the `dataStore` and compare the stored theme value in `viewModel` with the latest value which `dataStore` live data gives, if they are not same `recreate()`.  *(I've typed flow by mistake in the code of my answer)*

Comment: There are actually 3 values, two Int's for the themes itself and one boolean for the darkmode which I have to check for.

Comment: What are you using to toggle between light and dark mode. `AppDelegate` or `setTheme`?

Comment: setTheme as shown

Comment: Then why are you using 3 values?

Comment: I need the darkMode boolean to identify when either the light or the dark theme is needed, as well as the corresponding Integer of the theme that's about to be executed in setTheme()

Comment: You don't need these many variables, only `darkMode` boolean is enough for your use case.

Comment: It is not only for switching between dark and light mode, also between different colors (themes)

Comment: If you have multiple themes, you can still make it work with only one variable. You can use a single `int` variable to store the theme state and switch accordingly, using `when` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I have now adopted it and storing my current theme in one int value.